# Finding Vertical and Horizontal Asymptote lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what is the vertical and horizontal asymptote lines of the equation $y=\frac{2}{x+1}+2$. I think the vertical asymptote line is $x=-1$ but am lost on how to find the horizontal asymptote line.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the vertical asymptote.  For the horizontal, get common denominators:
$$
\frac{2}{x+1}+2=\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{2(x+1)}{x+1}=\frac{2x+3}{x+1}.
$$
Do you know how to get horizontal asymptotes from that?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to observe $\frac{2}{x+1}$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.

As $x\to \pm \infty$, notice that $\frac{2}{x+1} \to 0 \implies y \to 2$. Hence the horizontal asymptote is $y = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Express $x$ in terms of $y$. The result should be a fraction. Equate the denominator, which should be a function of $y$, to $0$ and solve for $y$. The real roots of that equation in $y$, subtracted from $y$ and equated to $0$, will be the equations of the sought-after horizontal asymptotes.